# How to use aapt to get pkg info (AndroidManifest)

Tags: android, aapt

I'm trying to get the AndroidManifest from an app using the following:
`aapt dump badging <path-to-apk>`

But I keep getting `W/asset   ( 2644): Asset path /data/app/com.UCMobile.intl-1.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
ERROR: dump failed because assets could not be loaded`

What am I missing here? =/

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a step by step guide to get the manifest file:

1. download `apktool.jar`, `apktool.bat` from  http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/
2. put both files in one folder, i.e. `apktool.bat` and `apktool.jar`
3. open a dos box (`cmd.exe`) and change into that folder; verify that a Java Environment is installed
4. Start: `apktool decode [apk file]`

   *Intermediate result*: resource files, `AndroidManifest.xml`

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file/15395456#15395456) for more and alternative descriptions.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that aapt operates on the files ON THE MACHINE not on the mobile (apk file path in your post command indicates android device). First "adb pull" the apk file to a known directory then inspect the apk file.